# using dist folder instead of root for npm package

Tags: node.js, npm-link

I created a Node.js package and the files to be referenced by the user of this package reside in a `dist` folder inside the package.

Now I don't want to use `require('my-package/dist/feature')` but `require('my-package/feature')`.

I set `main` and `files` to this in `package.json` but when testing the package with `npm link` locally, I still have to use `require('my-package/dist/feature')` otherwise I get `Cannot find module` errors.

`package.json`:

```
  "main": "dist",
  "files": ["dist"],
```

Comment: You need an `index.js` in the root of your package that `import`s and re-`exports` the features of your package that you want to make public (i.e. `import` from another package).

Comment: `"main": "dist/index.js",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `index.js` in the root of your package that [`import`s and re-`exports`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports) the features of your package that you want to make public (i.e. `import` from another package):

```
export { feature1 } from 'feature1';
export { feature2a, feature2b } from 'feature2';
export * from 'feature3';
// etc
```

You can then `import` them into other projects as:

```
import { feature1, feature2a } from 'my-package';
```

Comment: this shouldn't be the correct answer as it doesn't allow `import something from 'my-package/feature', also not a good practice for tree-shaking